# commitEditingStyle in tableview datasource methods

Tags: iphone

i had nsmutablearray hold data one two three four five...

i need to delete data from my commitEditingStyle...

```
   - (void)tableView:(UITableView *)aTableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath 
    {

        if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete) 
        {

        [favoriteListArray removeObjectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    //  [tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
  //    [tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:[favoriteListArray arrayWithObject:indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
        }
    }
```

What do to delete selected list.

my application get crashed

*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Invalid update: invalid number of sections.  The number of sections contained in the table view after the update (4) must be equal to the number of sections contained in the table view before the update (5), plus or minus the number of sections inserted or deleted (0 inserted, 0 deleted).'

@thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to delete NSMutable Array when it has no objects then simply check

```
if([favoriteListArray count]<1)

    {
       [favoriteListArray release];//if it is not autorelease;
       favoriteListArray=nil;
    }
```

**Edit:**

for deleting entry from table

you need to reload the table now NSMutableArray not having that entry so this time it shows updated result.

Comment: i want to delete selected row

Answer (score 0):

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)aTableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath 
{

    if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete) 
    {
        UIDevice *device_ID = [UIDevice currentDevice];
        NSString *deviceUDID = [device_ID uniqueIdentifier];
        NSLog(@"deviceUDID %@",deviceUDID);
        NSString *url=@"http://partytemperature.com/favoritevent_delete.php?eventid=";
        url=[url stringByAppendingFormat:@"%@&deviceid=%@",aEventInfo.event_ID,deviceUDID];
        NSLog(@"Url value %@",url);
        [self parsePopularEvent:[[NSURL alloc]initWithString:url]];
        [[[favoriteListArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.section]eventListArray] removeObjectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        [tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade]; 
        [tableView reloadData];
    }
}

-(void)parsePopularEvent:(NSURL *)url{
    NSXMLParser *xmlParser=[[NSXMLParser alloc]initWithContentsOfURL:url];
    XMLParser *parser=[[XMLParser alloc]initXMLParser];
    [xmlParser setDelegate:parser];
    BOOL success;
    success=[xmlParser parse];
    if (success) {
        NSLog(@"Parsed Success");
    }
    else

    NSLog(@"Error!!!!!");
```

}

This is deleting option which i done its working perfect........

but i can send only one request for my web service. using xmlparser... I need send every deleted request to my web-service.